# How do you obtain the user's ip address for the google reCAPTCHA request? PHP Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ip, recaptcha

I have implemented the Google ReCaptcha where it verifies just the g-captcha-response from the $_POST and my secret. However, I don't know how to obtain or send the remote ip. I'm using Laravel 5 and I'm new to php in general. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: assign $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to a variable. Please refer to PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel,the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object has a method called `ip()`, so you can use that:

Using Request Facade:

```
$ipAddress = Request::ip();
```

If you have an instance of request, i.e: `$request` then you may try this:

```
$ipAddress = $request->ip();
```

Also you may try this way:

```
$ipAddress = app('request')->ip();
```

Alternatively you may use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` as already commented.